# Get MAC and DHCP server from ipconfig

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, winpe, ipconfig

I am writing a script in a WinPE environment where I want to find my PXE server and send it my MAC address to retrieve provisioning scripts.

Here's what I have to deal with:

- The server will have multiple network adapters. Only one is connected to my PXE server.
- The PXE server is always also the DHCP server on that network.
- There may be other DHCP servers connected to the other NICs.
- The PXE server is also listening on port 80.
- cURL is available in the WinPE image.

I want the final line in the script to be:

```
curl -s -o %TEMP%/setup.cmd http://%PXE_IP%/cblr/svc/op/script/system/%MY_MAC%/?script=setup.cmd
```

I see that I get all the necessary info from `ipconfig /all` but I have no idea how to parse that output.

For example I can do

```
for /f "tokens=15 delims= " %%X in ('ipconfig /all ^| find "DHCP Server"') do echo %%X
```

This gives me the IP addresses for the DHCP servers on each adapter. I can determine which is correct. But then what? I need the corresponding MAC address for that adapter. That information is in the output, but I threw it away with my `find`.

Comment: Use a `FOR /F` command to parse the output of the `IPCONFIG` command.  You will probably want to pipe the output of `IPCONFIG` to the `FIND` command as well.

Comment: That way I can get for example the DHCP server. But once I find the correct DHCP server, how do I know which MAC to use for that one? AFAIK I cannot get the ipconfig for only a specific adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `wmic` instead of ipconfig, if possible on WinPE.

To get all active Interfaces

```
wmic nic where NetConnectionStatus=2 get InterfaceIndex, MACAddress,NetConnectionID /format:csv
```

> MyComputer, 13, 40:47:40:4D:42:4C,Wireless Network Connection
>   MyComputer, 58, 00:50:56:C2:20:01,VMware Network Adapter VMnet1

And then you only need to combine this with the dhcp-server for each InterfaceIndex

```
wmic nicconfig get InterfaceIndex,DHCPServer /format:csv
```

> MyComputer,10.0.0.1, 13
>   MyComputer,, 58

For fetching the data you use something like this

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM *** Delete all previous variables beginning with "nic_"
for /F "delims==" %%V in ('set nic[ 2^> nul') do set "%%V="

for /F "skip=2 tokens=1-4* delims=," %%1 in ('"wmic nic where NetConnectionStatus=2 get InterfaceIndex, MACAddress,NetConnectionID,Status /format:csv"') do (
  echo DEBUG: "%%4",%%2,%%3
  set "nic[%%2].mac=%%3"
)

for /F "skip=2 delims=" %%L in ('"wmic nicconfig get InterfaceIndex,DHCPServer,IPAddress /format:csv"') do (
  set "line=%%L"
  set "line=""!line:,=,"!"" --- Pump up the csv line with quotes to avoid empty columns col1,,col2 transformed to "col1","","col3"
  for /F "tokens=1-4* delims=," %%1 in ("!line!") do (
    if "%%~2" NEQ "" (
        set nic[%%~3].dhcpServer=%%~2
    )
  )
)

set nic
```

Output:

> nic[13].dhcpServer=10.0.0.1
>   nic[13].mac=40:47:40:4D:42:4C
>   nic[58].mac=00:50:56:C2:20:01

Btw. I'm cheating a bit, as I always fetch one extra column that I doesn't need, but it's for avoiding the problem, that the last column ends with a CR character.

Comment: Unfortunately wmic is not available in WinPE. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script from my older project (cca 2½ years ago) simulating `wmic` results via parsing `ipconfig /ALL` output. Adapting it to get **DHCP Server** instead of <strike>IPv4 Address</strike> and <strike>IPv6 Address</strike> should not be a tough job for you…

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
  set "HostName="
  set "NetConID="
  set "IP_Addr4="
  set "IP_Addr6="
  set "MAC_Addr="
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in ('ipconfig /ALL') do (
  set "foo=%%~G"
  if not "!foo:Host name=!"=="!foo!" (
    for %%I in (%%~H) do if not "%%~I"=="" set "HostName=%%~I"
  )
  if "!foo:adapter=!"=="!foo!" (
    if not "!foo:Physical Address=!"=="!foo!" (
      for %%I in (%%~H) do if not "%%~I"=="" set "MAC_Addr=%%~I"
    )
    if not "!foo:IPv4 Address=!"=="!foo!" (
      for %%I in (%%~H) do if not "%%~I"=="" set "IP_Addr4=%%~I"
      set "IP_Addr4=!IP_Addr4:(preferred)=!"
    )
    if not "!foo:local IPv6 Address=!"=="!foo!" (
      for %%I in (%%~H) do (
        if not "%%~I"=="" (
          for /F "delims=%%" %%p in ("%%~I") Do set "IP_Addr6=%%~p"
          rem set "IP_Addr6=!IP_Addr6:(preferred)=!"
        )
      )
    )
  ) else (
    if not "!IP_Addr6!,!IP_Addr4!"=="," (
      @echo #!HostName!,!NetConID!,{"!IP_Addr4!","!IP_Addr6!"},!MAC_Addr!
    )
    set "MAC_Addr="
    set "IP_Addr4="
    set "IP_Addr6="
    set "NetConID=!foo:*adapter =!"
  )
)
if not "!IP_Addr6!,!IP_Addr4!"=="," (
  @echo =!HostName!,!NetConID!,{"!IP_Addr4!","!IP_Addr6!"},!MAC_Addr!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution can be used or not in your case to get the IP and the MAC address ?

```batch
@echo off
Title Get IP and MAC Address
@for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 -n 1 %ComputerName% ^| findstr [') do (
    set "PXE_IP=%%a"
)

@For /f %%a in ('getmac /NH /FO Table') do  (
    @For /f %%b in ('echo %%a') do (
        If /I NOT "%%b"=="N/A" (
            Set "MY_MAC=%%b"
        )
    )
)
echo PXE_IP : %PXE_IP%
echo MAC Address : %MY_MAC%
echo(
echo curl -s -o %TEMP%/setup.cmd http://%PXE_IP%/cblr/svc/op/script/system/%MY_MAC%/?script=setup.cmd
pause>nul
```